# How to included the legend next to each subplot and custom resize the bar chart in Plotly Express charts

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-python, plotly-express

Below code is used to create subplot charts in ploty express, and the legend are all shown in the right hand side corner.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

specs = [[{'type':'pie'}, {"type": "pie"}], [{"type": "bar"}, {"type": "bar"}]]
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, specs=specs, shared_yaxes = True,subplot_titles=['Pie Chart A',
                                                                                     'Pie Chart B',
                                                                                     'Bar Chart A', 
                                                                                     ],
                      )
                    
                    
# Pie chart
df1 = df['Generation'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
                            labels = df1['index'], 
                            values = df1['count'],
                            hole = 0.6,
                            marker_colors = ['#353837','#646665', '#8e9492',],
                            textinfo='percent + value + label',
                            textposition = ['inside', 'inside','outside']
                            ), 1, 1)  


df2 = df['Education_Level'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
                            labels = df2['index'], 
                            values = df2['count'],
                            hole = 0.6,
                            marker_colors = ['#353837','#646665', '#8e9492','#acadac','#f0f2f0'],
                            textinfo='percent + value + label',
                            textposition = ['inside', 'inside','inside','inside','outside']
                            ), 1, 2)  

df4 = df.groupby(['Generation'])['Education_Level'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
df4['%'] = 100 * df4['count']/  df4.groupby(['Generation'])['count'].transform('sum')

# Bar Chart's
# Millenials Trace
trace1  = go.Bar(
                        x = df4[df4['Generation']=='Millenials']['Education_Level'],
                        y = df4[df4['Generation']=='Millenials']['count'],
                        name = 'Millenials',
                        text = ['M, {}, {:.0%}'.format(v, p/100) for v,p in zip( df4[df4['Generation']=='Millenials']['count'],  
                                                                             df4[df4['Generation']=='Millenials']['%'])],
                        textposition = ['inside', 'inside', 'inside', 'inside', 'outside'],
                        textfont_size=15,
                        marker_color = ['#455f66']*len(df4['Education_Level'])
                       )

# Generation X Trace
trace2  = go.Bar(
                        x = df4[df4['Generation']=='Generation X']['Education_Level'],
                        y = df4[df4['Generation']=='Generation X']['count'],
                        name = 'Generation X',
                        text = ['GX, {}, {:.0%}'.format(v, p/100) for v,p in zip( df4[df4['Generation']=='Generation X']['count'],  
                                                                             df4[df4['Generation']=='Generation X']['%'])],
                        textposition = ['inside', 'inside', 'inside', 'outside', 'outside'],
                        textfont_size=15,
                        marker_color = ['#7da8b3']*len(df4['Education_Level'])
                       )


# Boomers Trace
trace3  = go.Bar(
                        x = df4[df4['Generation']=='Boomers']['Education_Level'],
                        y = df4[df4['Generation']=='Boomers']['count'],
                        name = 'Boomers',
                        text = ['B, {}, {:.0%}'.format(v, p/100) for v,p in zip( df4[df4['Generation']=='Boomers']['count'],  
                                                                             df4[df4['Generation']=='Boomers']['%'])],
                        textfont_size=15,
                        textposition = 'outside',
                        marker_color = ['#9bd9e8']*len(df4['Education_Level'])
                       )


# Appending trace
fig.append_trace(trace1,2,1)
fig.append_trace(trace2,2,1)
fig.append_trace(trace3,2,1)


fig.update_annotations(font_size=12)
fig.update_layout(height=550,
                    width=750,
                    showlegend=True, 
                  title=dict(text="<b> [Summary] </b> Highlevel Overview ",
                             font=dict(
                                        family="Arial",
                                        size=20,
                                        color='#283747'))
                  )  

fig.show()
```

And the below is the output I get  in Plotly Express subplots based on the above code

[image]

How can I **include the chart legends next to each subplots and custom resize the bar chart**  in Plotly Express Subplots.

Comment: Does this link help https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-subplots-with-individual-legends/1754/18?

Comment: @Hamzah Nope this link did not help me.

Comment: As you might read in the link, there is customization option for each legend.